# Any way around InnoDB autoincrementing on IGNORE?

Tags: mysql, innodb, auto-increment, on-duplicate-key

With InnoDB, anytime you perform an INSERT IGNORE or an ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, it will auto_increment the table regardless of whether anything was inserted or not.

This problem is pathetically annoying.

Any simple ways around this?

Comment: It's not a problem, it's a desired feature. There **shouldn't** be a way around it, but I sense rep hunters suggesting altering the table and resetting the increment count. Just don't do it.

Comment: Many moons ago I was convinced to just let it go and not worry about monotonically increasing ids in database tables.  I think I've had a happier life since

Comment: Just curious, what app are you working on where this is even an issue? Let the database do it's thing. If you are trying to get last insert id, then you should be wrapping queries within a transaction. And if you are worried about running out of ids, be sure your id col is set to unsigned.

Comment: Yeah I think the OCD in me needs to let it go. The problem is that I'm running cron jobs that regularly check for data, and then insert anything new into the database. So everytime it runs the script, I end up with huge gaps in autoincrement.

Comment: @NathanWaters: I would focus on figuring out why transactions are failing rather than worrying about gaps in autoincrement ids.

Comment: Once you realize that the purpose of auto_increment is to define a row uniquely, you're good for life. That's all it does, makes a record get a unique number. Don't worry about gaps. However, as @MikePurcell says - find out why transactions are failing.

Answer (score 0):

You can mimic the INSERT IGNORE behavior using a special mutex table.

Refer this article :

[Avoiding auto-increment holes on InnoDB with INSERT IGNORE](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/11/29/avoiding-auto-increment-holes-on-innodb-with-insert-ignore/)

Answer (score 0):

InnoDB allows you to roll back transactions. This means you can insert into one table, fail to insert a related record into another table, and then rollback the first insert. During that time, other inserts could happen in the first table which need a unique ID also. In that case, you can't give up the auto increment that was handed out.

On INSERT IGNORE, InnoDB can only tell if there is already a record by trying to insert. It needs the auto increment before insert. You can't search then insert, because other processes may be doing the same thing and inserting the same record in the time between the select and insert.

You should worry about it unless you think you will exceed the max value for the field. For bigint, that's very large. Facebook uses bigint and hasn't run out yet.